# tutorial for iCloud and native iPhone app synchronization

Tags: iphone, icloud

Any one has some good tutorial for iCloud and native iPhone app synchronization.
Please provide me a link or example for iCloud.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Please post some code where you stuck. Don't expect someone to write code for you.

Comment: the best list of tutorials you will find here http://bit.ly/SHNFiG

Comment: search for Marin Todorov's ilcoud Demo project.. You Will get through it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the sample code from this below url :

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=add-an-icloud-photo-gallery-to-your-app-with-mticloudphotogallery-library

Cheers :)

Comment: It takes time for loading. Don't be vexed..

Comment: Nice one friend. Good Trace..